# Copying an object with pointers in it to another object

Tags: c++, object, pointers, copy

I am trying to copy an object to another object. But my first object has a property which points to another variable inside the same object. Example:

`int* a;`

What I want to do is make a copy of that object but through my debugger I can clearly see that

`int* a;`

of my original object points to exactly the same address as the `int* a;` of my copied object when I do not want it to do that.

I want it to point to its own place in the memory and not alter the original object.

Comment: You have to write code for that. Copying a pointer does not change it.

Comment: Use a copy constructor, but make sure you follow [The Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)

Comment: You might want to check deep copy.

Comment: You should show some code to clarify what you mean, otherwise people will have to guess.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a copy constructor for this purpose.
Basic copy operation will copy in surface. (member wise copy)

```
YourClass::YourClass(const YourClass& p) {
    x = p.x;
    y = p.y;
    *a = *(p.a);
}
```

You should allocate space for a pointer in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to write an assignment operator and a copy constructor.  I'll point you to a more complete article which describes both.  You can also search the web for more examples if necessary.
http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/

If you have a C++ 11 compliant compiler then I would also look into using smart pointers if I were you.